# Compiling appropriate gulp file

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-sass

Using Gulp & Gulp-sass which makes use of 'gulp.watch', how can I return the directory name of the changed item on the watchlist so I can then compile the sass to css?

This is how I currently have it; as you can see there is only one directory being compiled which is theme 1. If theme 2 or 3 changes in the SASS, the theme 1 css will be updated. I want it to be conditional so either one changes according to the different changes.

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./wp-content/themes/1/assets/sass/**/*.scss')
         .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('./wp-content/themes/1/'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./wp-content/themes/1/assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./wp-content/themes/2/assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./wp-content/themes/3/assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is awfully hard-coded, this has been my solution which I just found.

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    // return gulp.src('./wp-content/themes/giggleselc/assets/sass/**/*.scss')
    //      .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    //      .pipe(gulp.dest('./wp-content/themes/giggleselc/'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
    var n1 = gulp.watch('./wp-content/themes/1/assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    var n2 = gulp.watch('./wp-content/themes/2/assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    var n3 = gulp.watch('./wp-content/themes/3/assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);

    n1.on('change', function(f) {
        return gulp.src('./wp-content/themes/1/assets/sass/**/*.scss')
            .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./wp-content/themes/1/'));
    });
    n2.on('change', function(f) {
        console.log('Change Event:', f);
        return gulp.src('./wp-content/themes/2/assets/sass/**/*.scss')
            .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./wp-content/themes/2/'));
    });
    n3.on('change', function(f) {
        return gulp.src('./wp-content/themes/3/assets/sass/**/*.scss')
            .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./wp-content/themes/3/'));
    });
});
```